# How do you reverse the sorting order in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mylogs` WHERE `username` LIKE :username LIMIT 0 , :limit");
    $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

I then use a while loop to print out the database in a table format.

Great, whats the issue?

Well my issue is I want to completely REVERSE the order that is returned.

I tried ORDER BY but since I have a WHERE I didn't know exactly where to plug it in.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: `SELECT...FROM..WHERE...ORDER BY...LIMIT`

Comment: order by goes after where and before limit.

Comment: [The `ORDER BY` goes retween your `WHERE` clause and your `LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reverse an `ORDER BY` clause, append `DESC` to it. Like this:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare(sprintf('SELECT * FROM `mylogs`
                                WHERE `username`
                                LIKE ?
                                ORDER BY `username`
                                LIMIT %d', intval($limit)));
$query->execute(array($username));
```

Also, the limits in `LIMIT X, Y` in **PDO** *can't be placeholders*. Use `sprintf()` instead, this way you can guarantee the number(s) to be integer(s).

Addition: Don't use the `LIKE` keyword unless you really need a wildcard search.

Comment: God damn it thank you. I was trying WHERE `username` LIKE ORDER BY :username DESC but it wouldn't work now I know why thanks

Comment: @Swaly Accept the answer if case you found it useful.

Comment: I gave up yesterday kept telling me to wait, thanks for the reminder.